# joblib.load __main__ AttributeError

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, pickle

I'm starting to dive into deploying a predictive model to a web app using Flask, and unfortunately getting stuck at the starting gate.

**What I did:**

I pickled my model in my **model.py** program:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib

class NeuralNetwork():
    """
    Two (hidden) layer neural network model. 
    First and second layer contain the same number of hidden units
    """
    def __init__(self, input_dim, units, std=0.0001):
        self.params = {}
        self.input_dim = input_dim

        self.params['W1'] = np.random.rand(self.input_dim, units)
        self.params['W1'] *= std
        self.params['b1'] = np.zeros((units))

        self.params['W2'] = np.random.rand(units, units)
        self.params['W2'] *= std * 10  # Compensate for vanishing gradients
        self.params['b2'] = np.zeros((units))

        self.params['W3'] = np.random.rand(units, 1)
        self.params['b3'] = np.zeros((1,))

model = NeuralNetwork(input_dim=12, units=64)

#####THIS RIGHT HERE ##############
joblib.dump(model, 'demo_model.pkl')
```

then I created an **api.py** file in the same directory as my *demo_model.pkl*, per this tutorial (https://blog.hyperiondev.com/index.php/2018/02/01/deploy-machine-learning-models-flask-api/):

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sklearn.externals import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')


# create endpoint for the predictions (HTTP POST requests)
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def make_prediction():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('index.html', label='3')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # LOAD MODEL WHEN APP RUNS ####
    model = joblib.load('demo_model.pkl')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

I also made a templates/index.html file in the same directory with this info:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NN Model as Flask API</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Boston Housing Price Predictor</h1>
        <form action="/predict" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" value="Upload">
            <input type="submit" value="Predict"> {% if label %} {{ label }} {% endif %}
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

running:

```
>> python api.py
```

gives me an error with the pickler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 22, in <module>
    model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 578, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 508, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1043, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1342, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1396, in find_class
    return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'NeuralNetwork'
```

Why is the main module of the program getting involved with my NeuralNetwork model? I'm very confused at the moment... any advice would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Adding a class definition `class NeuralNetwork(object): pass` to my **api.py** program fixed the bug.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sklearn.externals import joblib


class NeuralNetwork(object):
    pass


app = Flask(__name__)
```

***If anyone would be willing to offer me an explanation of what was going on that would be hugely appreciated!***

Comment: Try changing `class NeuralNetwork():` to `class NeuralNetwork(object):` in the code creating `demo_model.pkl` (replace `object` with a class name if you want to inherit one) and re-create `demo_model.pkl`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu No luck.. renamed class to `NeuralNetwork(object):` and still get the same error. I tried pickling a couple different things, still get the same error when I use `model = joblib.load('model.pkl')`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The specific exception you're getting refers to attributes in `__main__`, but that's mostly a red herring. I'm pretty sure the issue actually has to do with how you dumped the instance.

Pickle does not dump the actual code classes and functions, only their names. It includes the name of the module each one was defined in, so it can find them again. If you dump a class defined in a module you're running as a script, it will dump the name `__main__` as the module name, since that's what Python uses as the name for the main module (as seen in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` boilerplate code).

When you run `model.py` as a script and pickle an instance of a class defined in it, that class will be saved as `__main__.NeuralNetwork` rather than `model.NeuralNetwork`. When you run some other module and try to load the pickle file, Python will look for the class in the `__main__` module, since that's where the pickle data tells it to look. This is why you're getting an exception about attributes of `__main__`.

To solve this you probably want to change how you're dumping the data. Instead of running `model.py` as a script, you should probably run some other module and have it do `import model`, so you get the module under it's normal name. (I suppose you could have `model.py` import itself in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, but that's super ugly and awkward). You probably also need to avoid recreating and dumping the instance unconditionally when the `model` is imported, since that needs to happen when you load the pickle file (and I assume the whole point of the pickle is to avoid recreating the instance from scratch).

So remove the dumping logic from the bottom of `model.py`, and add a new file like this:

```
# new script, dump_model.py, does the creation and dumping of the NeuralNetwork

from sklearn.externals import joblib

from model import NeuralNetwork

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = NeuralNetwork(input_dim=12, units=64)
    joblib.dump(model, 'demo_model.pkl')
```

When you dump the `NeuralNetwork` using this script, it will correctly identify `model` as the module the class was defined in, and so the loading code will be able to import that module and make an instance of the class correctly.

Your current "fix" for the issue (defining an empty `NeuralNetwork` class in the `__main__` module when you are loading the object) is probably a bad solution. The instance you get from loading the pickle file will be an instance of the new class, not the original one. It will be loaded with the attributes of the old instance, but it won't have any methods or other class variables set on it (which isn't an issue with the class you've shown, but probably will be for any kind of object that's more complicated).

Comment: Yes! that was it thanks! I was running the model creation as a script ( I had a model.py file, but the saved pickled file came off my jupyter notebook). Great explanation, thanks for sharing. Is there a way to show the full object notation of the pickled model? (As you shown above, it was probably named as `__main__.NeuralNetwork` instead of `model.NeuralNetwork`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Keras` library to build your neural network then `pickle` will not work. `pickle` only works fine the model built using `scikit` libraries. Save your neural network model using `json` .

`Keras` provides the ability to describe any model using `JSON` format with a `to_json()` function. This can be saved to file and later loaded via the `model_from_json()` function that will create a new model from the JSON specification.

```
# serialize model to JSON
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open(“model.json”, “w”) as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# serialize weights to HDF5
    model.save_weights(“model.h5”)
    print(“Saved model to disk”)

# later…

# load json and create model
    json_file = open(‘model.json’, ‘r’)
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights(“model.h5”)
    print(“Loaded model from disk”)
```