# pickle/joblib AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'thing' in pytest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytest, pickle, joblib

I have built a custom sklearn pipeline, as follows:

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SelectColumnsTransfomer(features_to_use),
    ToDummiesTransformer('feature_0', prefix='feat_0', drop_first=True,  dtype=bool), # Dummify customer_type
    ToDummiesTransformer('feature_1', prefix='feat_1'), # Dummify the feature
    ToDummiesTransformer('feature_2', prefix='feat_2'), # Dummify 
    ToDummiesTransformer('feature_3', prefix='feat_3'), # Dummify
)
pipeline.fit(df)
```

The classes `SelectColumnsTransfomer` and `ToDummiesTransformer` are custom sklearn steps implementing `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`.
To serialise this object I use

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'data_pipeline.joblib')
```

but when I do deserialise with

```
pipeline = joblib.load('data_pipeline.joblib')
```

I get `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'SelectColumnsTransfomer'`.

I have read other similar questions and followed the instruction in this blogpost [here](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html), but couldn't solve the issue. 
I am copying pasting the classes, and importing them in the code. If i create a simplified version of this exercise, the whole thing works, the problem occurs because i am running some tests with pytest, and when i run pytest it seems it doesn't see my custom classes, in fact there is this other part of the error 
`self = <sklearn.externals.joblib.numpy_pickle.NumpyUnpickler object at 0x7f821508a588>, module = '__main__', name = 'SelectColumnsTransfomer'` which is hinting me that the `NumpyUnpickler` doesn't see the `SelectColumnsTransfomer` even if in the test it is imported.

My test code

```
import pytest
from app.pipeline import * # the pipeline objects 
                          # SelectColumnsTransfomer and ToDummiesTransformer 
                          # are here!


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def clf():
    pipeline = joblib.load("persistence/data_pipeline.joblib")
    return clf

def test_fake(clf):
    assert True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [joblib.load \_\_main\_\_ AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621169/joblib-load-main-attributeerror)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when I was trying to save a Pytorch class like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class custom(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(custom, self).__init__()
        print("Class loaded")

model = custom()
```

And then using Joblib to dump this model like so:

```
from joblib import dump
dump(model, 'some_filepath.jobjib')
```

The issue was I was running the code above in a [Kaggle](https://kaggle.com) kernel. And then downloading the dumped file and trying to load it with this script locally:

```
from joblib import load
model = load(model, 'some_filepath.jobjib')
```

The way I fixed the issue was to **run all of these code snippets locally on my computer instead of creating the class and dumping it on Kaggle, but loading it on my local machine**. Wanted to add this here because the comments on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192673/9179875) by @DarioB confused me in their reference to a 'function' which didn't apply in my simpler case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with sklearn and complex pipelines.

I used cloudpickle 2.0.0 /py3.10 (instead of pickle or joblib) to dump the model and then load it with joblib without error.

Hope it could help.

Note: the model was dump from a jupyter notebook and load inside a python script.