# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DataFrameSelector' on <module '__main__'>

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to load a pickled model but get this error:

```
model = joblib.load('pred.pkl')
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'DataFrameSelector'
```

and here is the way to dump the model:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(best_rf, 'leadpred.pkl')
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you import sklearn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [joblib.load \_\_main\_\_ AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621169/joblib-load-main-attributeerror)

Answer (score 0):

The file that executes the model needs to import `sklearn`.

Comment: you mean import sklearn before loading the model? If yes, it is already imported.