# Custom simple linear model: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'dummy' on <module '__main__'>

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to store the class object which is the simple linear model, want to fit and store using `joblib`.

When I try to re-use the `fitted` object from other location, I am getting `AttributeError`

**Code:**

```
import joblib

class dummy:
    def __init__(self, some_param=None):
        self.some_param = some_param
        
    def fit(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        return
   
    def predict(self, x):
        return (self.a * x) + self.b
    
check_test = dummy()
check_test.fit(2,3)

joblib.dump(check_test, "dummy.joblib")
```

From other location:

```
dummy = joblib.load("../path/to/dummy.joblib")
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'dummy' on <module '**main**'>

Comment: `check_test = dummy().fit(2,3)` sets `check_test = None` because `fit()` returns None

Comment: @Dennis I have updated the code. Can you check now?

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621169/joblib-load-main-attributeerror